# Solving an equation $\pmod {13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose:

$$1 + \frac12 +\frac13 + \dots + \frac1{23} = \frac{a}{23!}$$

I would like to find $a \pmod {13}$.

My attempt:
I'm attempting to use Wilson's theorem which states:

$$(n-1)!= -1 \pmod n$$

consider: 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{23!a}{13} & = 23\times22\times21\dots\times14\times a\times(12!) &\\
&= -23\times22\times21\dots\times14\times a &\pmod {13} && \text{By Wilson's theorem}\\
&= -10\times9\times8\times\dots\times1\times a &\pmod{13} \\
&= -10!a &\pmod{13} \\
\end{align}$$

I have no idea where to go from here or even if I'm going in the right direction.
Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: You can just use wilson's theorem again and figure out what $11$^{-1}$ is

Comment: @Grand Apache I edited your question to add some formatting, hopefully I didn't change any of your meaning. Please see the link below for information on how to do this yourself:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting a common denominator $23!$ you will have to multiply every one by the numbers left to get a $23!$, I mean,

$a=23!+23!/2+23!/3+\ldots 23!/22 +22!$, but all this terms have a $13$ except for $23!/13$ so a first step is $a\equiv 23!/13$ (mod $13$).

Now by wilsons you know $12!\equiv -1$ (mod $13$) so you got $a\equiv -23*22*\ldots *14$ (mod $13$)

Which is equivalent to $a\equiv -10*9*\ldots *1$ and now we can cancel some terms, like $2*7 \equiv 1$, $3*9\equiv 1$, $4*10\equiv 1$ and $5*8\equiv 1$ and we reach $a\equiv -6$ (mod $13$)

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{23!}{k}\equiv 0\,\text{(mod $13$)}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,23$ *except* when $k=13$.

Sou you are left with $$
\begin{align}
a&\equiv \frac{23!}{13}=12!\cdot 14\cdot 15\cdots 23\\
&\equiv (-1)\cdot 1\cdot 2\cdots 10\equiv (-1)\cdot 12! \cdot 11^{-1}\cdot 12^{-1}\\
&\equiv (-1)\cdot (-1)\cdot (-2)^{-1}\cdot (-1)^{-1}\equiv -6\,\text{(mod $13$)}
\end{align}
$$

because $-2\cdot 6=-12\equiv 1\,\text{(mod $13$)}$.

Comment: I think he has already gone past this step. (but never mentioned he did but the calculation he shows make it seem like it anywas)